# JavaScript Blob to FormData with SAPUI5 mobile app

Tags: javascript, image, blob, sapui5, form-data

I know there are several threads about this topic, but I was not able to identify the problem in my case.

I have an application, where I upload an image to an endpoint-URL and after processing I'll receive a response. Works fine so far. The file is contained within a formdata object when using FileUploader-Control from SAPUI5.

When switching from file upload to "taking a picture with smartphone-camera", I dont have a file, I have an base64 dataurl (XString) image object.

```
var oImage = "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAABQAA…8ryQAbwUjsV5VUaAX/y+YSPJii2Z9GAAAAABJRU5ErkJggg=="} // some lines are missing > 1 million lines
```

I thought converting it to blob and appending it to FormData might be the solution, but it does not work at all.

```
var blob = this.toBlob(oImage)
console.log("Blob", blob); // --> Blob(857809) {size: 857809, type: "image/png"} size: 857809 type: "image/png" __proto__: Blob 

var formData = new window.FormData();
formData.append("files", blob, "test.png");
console.log("FormData", formData); // seems empty --> FormData {}__proto__: FormData
```

Functions (works fine from my perspective)

```
toBlob: function dataURItoBlob(dataURI) {
        var byteString = atob(dataURI.split(',')[1]);
        var mimeString = dataURI.split(',')[0].split(':')[1].split(';')[0]
        var ab = new ArrayBuffer(byteString.length);
        var ia = new Uint8Array(ab);
        for (var i = 0; i < byteString.length; i++) {
            ia[i] = byteString.charCodeAt(i);
        }
        var bb = new Blob([ab], {
            "type": mimeString
        });
        return bb;
},
```

This is my problem, FormData is empty and my POST-request throws an undefined error (Loading of data failed: TypeError: Cannot read property 'status' of undefined at constructor.eval (...m/resources/sap/ui/core/library-preload.js?eval:2183:566))

```
//Create JSON Model with URL
var oModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel();
var sHeaders = {
    "content-type": "multipart/form-data; boundary=---011000010111000001101001",
    "APIKey": "<<myKey>>"
};

var oData = {
    formData
};

oModel.loadData("/my-destination/service", oData, true, "POST", null, false, sHeaders);

oModel.attachRequestCompleted(function (oEvent) {
    var oData = oEvent.getSource().oData;
    console.log("Final Response XHR: ", oData);
});
```

Thanks for any hint

Comment: in the upload collection? I don't think I've ever changed anything about the input. at the end of the day the image file upload via pc itself is also a binary string.

Comment: sorry, I dont understand your comment. what are you referring to? what do you mean with "in the upload collection?"?

Comment: I mean - and haven't seen this in a little while - I think if I used the upload collection to open the phone camera, which it does automatically, the upload already works. which makes sense because a file at the end of the day is also an xstring. I'll look up my code tomorrow at work.

Comment: would be great, thank you.

Comment: in the meantime, this is the upload collection control: https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/sdk#/entity/sap.m.UploadCollection

Comment: got your point, you used upload collection for any device to fetch the picture. great idea, good hint. going forward on this.

Comment: @Jorg if you post an answer, something like "i would recommend using upload collection", I would accept it. I was not aware of this control and it fully satisfies my requirements... (all devices supported), If you also post some of your code, this would be really great.

Comment: would be also great to see how you POST something of your uploadcollection to an URL...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [upload collection](https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/sdk#/entity/sap.m.UploadCollection) is a complex standard control that can be used for attachment management. On desktop it opens a file dialog, on mobile it opens the ios or android photo options, which means picking a photo from the camera roll, or taking a new photo.

Fairly basic example, including the upload URL's and other handlers you'll need. More options are available, adjust to suit your needs. In your XML:

```
<UploadCollection 
    uploadUrl="{path:'Key',formatter:'.headerUrl'}/Attachments" 
    items="{Attachments}" 
    change="onAttachUploadChange" 
    fileDeleted="onAttachDelete" 
    uploadEnabled="true"
    uploadComplete="onAttachUploadComplete">
    <UploadCollectionItem 
        documentId="{DocID}"
        contributor="{CreatedBy}" 
        fileName="{ComponentName}" 
        fileSize="{path:'ComponentSize',formatter:'.formatter.parseFloat'}" 
        mimeType="{MIMEType}" 
        thumbnailUrl="{parts:[{path:'MIMEType'},{path:'DocID'}],formatter:'.thumbnailURL'}" 
        uploadedDate="{path:'CreatedAt', formatter:'.formatter.Date'}" url="{path:'DocID',formatter:'.attachmentURL'}" visibleEdit="false" 
        visibleDelete="true" />
</UploadCollection>
```

Here's the handlers. Especially the `onAttachUploadChange` is important. I should mention there's no explicit post. If the uploadUrl is set correctly a post is triggered anyway.

```
onAttachUploadChange: function(oEvent) {
  var csrf = this.getModel().getSecurityToken();
  var oUploader = oEvent.getSource();
  var fileName = oEvent.getParameter('files')[0].name;
  oUploader.removeAllHeaderParameters();
  oUploader.insertHeaderParameter(new UploadCollectionParameter({
    name: 'x-csrf-token',
    value: csrf
  }));
  oUploader.insertHeaderParameter(new UploadCollectionParameter({
    name: 'Slug',
    value: fileName
  }));
},

onAttachDelete: function(oEvent) {
  var id = oEvent.getParameter('documentId');
  var oModel = this.getModel();

  //set busy indicator maybe?

  oModel.remove(`/Attachments('${encodeURIComponent(id)}')`, {
    success: (odata, response) => {
      //successful removal
      //oModel.refresh();
    },
    error: err => console.log(err)
  });
},

onAttachUploadComplete: function(oEvent) {

  var mParams = oEvent.getParameter('mParameters');
  //handle errors an success in here. Check `mParams`. 
}
```

as for the formatters to determine URLs, that depends on your setup. In the case below, the stream is set up on the current binding contect, in which case this is one way to do it. You'll need the whole uri so including the `/sap/opu/...` etc bits.

```
  headerUrl: function() {
    return this.getModel().sServiceUrl + this.getView().getBindingContext().getPath()
  },
```

URL for attachments is similar, but generally points to an entity of the attachment service itself.

```
  attachmentURL: function(docid) {
    return this.getModel().sServiceUrl + "/Attachments('" + docid + "')/$value";
  },
```

You could fancy it up to check if it's an image, in which case you could include the mime type to show a thumbnail.

There might be better ways of doing this, but I've found this fairly flexible...

Comment: thanks! any idea how to pass custom XHR headers to the upload URL? API says to create UploadCollectionHeaderParameters, but these are not passed when using .upload() to an external server...

Comment: The code in the upload change handler adds headers like the csrf token. Not sure if the set is limited that way.

Comment: How @Jorg may i know how could we send the file data as form data something like this ... `var fd = new FormData();    
fd.append( 'file', input.files[0] );`  .... what could be a similar approach in sap ui5